# boostrap hide/show buttons based on variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, button

I'm (trying) to build an app based on boostrap/javascript/ and a nosql DB
a sort of small CRM/invoicing system
i need to show/hide button based on variable
for example for a quote, status could be "open", "lost" "win"
so on my quote details page when status of quote is open i want to show button 
- win (who change status of quote id in db to win and copy quote to an order)
-  lost (who change status of quote id in db)
but i want to hide button "Re-open" who change a cancel status to open 
and so on for my different status..

so want i'm looking for is a way to collapse/hide some button depending of the status of my quote (i put the status of my quote in a variable called quoteStatus)

any suggestion will be welcome

thanks

jeebee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that

```
if (quoteStatus==="value"){
    document.getElementById("buttonId").style.display='none';
}
else{
    document.getElementById("button").style.display='block';
}
```

this is just javascript, you could use jquery it will make it easier for you, so your code may look like that

```
if (quoteStatus==="value"){
        $("#buttonId").hide();
    }
    else{
        $("#buttonId").show();
    }
```

Comment: thanks It works for my with Jquery

Answer (score 0):

To get more positive reactions to your question you have to show some research effort. This question is not useful in that mather that you havent actually showed us what you have tried, and the purpose of your functionality have possibly been asked and explained before? [How to hide/show div based on variable using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521121/how-to-hide-show-div-based-on-variable-using-javascript). A div and a button is both elements.

Either way, as for your question, we need to know what you already have. The task in itself have several ways to be accomplished, and based on your existing code there could be a way to complete this task in a more correct manner than others.